# Combining a CONCAT in a SELECT statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to make a query that:

- Selects a persons first + last name (I did that with CONCAT/AS))
- Creates a column on the right that has the appointment type then another column for the appointment date

So the result should be:

```
Person | Appointment Type | Appointment Date
Michael Smith | Dental | Tuesda
```

These details are stored in 2 different tables.

Thank you!

---

Sorry, I forgot adding the tables:

Person

- person_id
- person_fname
- person_sname

Appointment

- appointment_id
- appointment_type
- appointment_date

PersonAppointment

- person_id
- appointment_id

Comment: Help us help you - share the tables' structures

Comment: I'm assuming you left out another table or column?  You need some way of linking the `person` table to the `appointment` table.

Comment: @sgeddes - Yes, sorry, I left out the table that links both together, I updated it now.

Comment: @Mureinik - Sorry, I updated my post

Comment: Look into using an `inner join`.  If you have trouble, post the query you tried with the error you are having.

Comment: @sgeddes - yep, thank you! I have now tried to add 

"ORDER BY Person DESC" but it's giving me a syntax error on the ORDER?

Comment: @Sanjar12345 You are probably missing your backticks around the column name.  Alternatively try `order by p.person_sname` or whatever you need instead of the derived field name.

Comment: Is this the right way to do it?

ORDER BY 'Person' DESC;

because if so, I put that at the end of the solution that was given below, and the ORDER by is already highlighted before I even write any tables, I think maybe it's in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Just inner join all three tables.

```
SELECT concat(p.person_fname, ' ', p.person_sname) `Person`,
       a.appointment_type `Appointment Type`,
       a.appointment_date `Appointment Date`
       FROM person p
            INNER JOIN personappointment pa
                       ON pa.person_id = p.person_id
            INNER JOIN appointment a
                       ON a.appointment_id = pa.appointment_id;
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I assume if I wanted to sort:

- Surname first
- IF two people have the same surname then first name alphabetically afterwards with a ORDER_BY ?

Comment: I did this, but it sorts it weirdly.. 

ORDER BY Person Desc